# Change from hour format to integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that has strings like '00:00' and I want to convert them to integer so I can plot them.

input '00:00'
output 0000

I have tried many ways but I did not get to any answers unfortunately. For example, I tried

```
   df1['Demand 07/05/2018'] = df1['Demand 07/05/2018'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(':'))
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use `replace()` method:

```
df1['Demand 07/05/2018']=df1['Demand 07/05/2018'].str.replace(':','')
```

If you want integer value then use `astype()` method after the above code(This method works only if you don't have NaN's in your 'Demand 07/05/2018' column):

```
df1['Demand 07/05/2018']=df1['Demand 07/05/2018'].astype(int)
```

Comment: You are still getting a string and not an integer with that solution.

Comment: @Hook because OP want string not integer